# Find the distance between letters in the keyboard

Tags: python, algorithm

I am trying to find the minimum distance between two letters in the 'qwerty' keyboard, for example if i evaluating letters `q` and `w` the minimum distance should be 1, since they are together in the keyboard, letter `q` and `e` minimum distance should be 2 since they are just two position away from each

I was trying to create a dictionary for doing like

```
coords = {
    'qw':1, 'qe':2, 'qr':3, 'qt':4, 'qy':5, 'qu':6, 'qi':7, 'qo':8, 'qp':9, 'qa':1, 'qs':2, 'qd':3, 
    'qf':4, 'qg':5, 'qh':6, 'qj':7, 'qk':8, 'ql':9, 'qz': 2, 'qx':3, 'qc':4, 'qv':5, 'qb':6, 'qn':7, 'qm':8,
    'q1':1, 'q2':1, 'q3':2, 'q4':3, 'q5':4, 'q6':5, 'q7':6, 'q8':7, 'q9':8}
```

for afterwards doing something like this to find the value of the minimum distance for each two letters ( in only did it for one-side pair for letter `q`)

```
sentence = 'qw'
grams = [sentence[i:i+N] for i in range(len(sentence)-N+1)]
[coords[i] for i in grams]
```

Comment: the main problem is that what you call distance and `coords` are misleading because are _relative_ to w... instead for your answer you should deal with _absolute_ data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of saving all possible pairs by hand, I think saving position of each letter and calculating distance would be much easier.

For example, `q` is (0, 0), `w` is (1, 0), `a` is (0, 1), and so on.
First element represents X coordinate and second element represents Y coordinate, starting from upper-left.

Calculating distance from each other can be automated easily(I chose [manhattan distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry), and you can choose distance calculation algorithm as you want)

```
key_positions = {"q": (0, 0), "w": (1, 0), ...}
def dist(c1, c2):
    pos1 = key_position[c1]
    pos2 = key_position[c2]
    return abs(pos1[0] - pos2[0]) + abs(pos1[1] - pos2[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can youse the `find()` function to find the indices of the first and second letters of your query and then calculate the difference between the indices to get the distance, like so:

```
text = 'qwerty'
query = 'qy'

index1 = text.find(query[0])
index2 = text.find(query[1])
distance = index2 - index1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a graph of the keys with a node for each key and an edge for each adjacency, then run BFS on the fly to get distances (or pre-compute for your dictionary if you prefer). BFS will be fast on such a small graph.